# Passed a parameter and managed to update that inside the function - Python

Tags: python, function, pysimplegui

I saw a sample demo code from PySimpleGUI and I'm still not sure if how the window variable

The window was passed as an argument to the_thread() function and somehow it managed to do some operations for window variable like **window.write_event_value** which is inside the main function.

I have a cp(values) inside the main that proves that it was added.

Can anyone explain to me how is that possible?

The

```
import threading
import time
import PySimpleGUI as sg


THREAD_EVENT = '-THREAD-'

cp = sg.cprint

def the_thread(window):

    i = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        cp('This keeps on running')
        window.write_event_value('-THREAD-', (threading.current_thread().name, i))      # Data sent is a tuple of thread name and counter
        cp('This is cheating from the thread', c='white on green')
        i += 1


def main():

    layout = [  [sg.Text('Output Area - cprint\'s route to here', font='Any 15')],
                [sg.Multiline(size=(65,20), key='-ML-', autoscroll=True, reroute_stdout=True, write_only=True, reroute_cprint=True)],
                [sg.T('Input so you can see data in your dictionary')],
                [sg.Input(key='-IN-', size=(30,1))],
                [sg.B('Start A Thread'), sg.B('Dummy'), sg.Button('Exit')]  ]

    window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)

    while True:             # Event Loop
        event, values = window.read()
        
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break
        if event.startswith('Start'):
            threading.Thread(target=the_thread, args=(window,), daemon=True).start()
        if event == THREAD_EVENT:
            cp(f'Data from the thread ', colors='white on purple', end='')
            cp(f'{values[THREAD_EVENT]}', colors='white on red')

        cp(values)
    window.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I tried to reply your question, but not understood what question it is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for being noob, looks like the reason it gets modified on a separate function is because it's a mutable object.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what the question is.
Try to explain this script.

1. Define the layout of window

```py
    layout = [  [sg.Text('Output Area - cprint\'s route to here', font='Any 15')],
                [sg.Multiline(size=(65,20), key='-ML-', autoscroll=True, reroute_stdout=True, write_only=True, reroute_cprint=True)],
                [sg.T('Input so you can see data in your dictionary')],
                [sg.Input(key='-IN-', size=(30,1))],
                [sg.B('Start A Thread'), sg.B('Dummy'), sg.Button('Exit')]  ]
```

2. Define a window by

```py
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)
```

3. While loop to handle events generated by action of mouse or keyboard inputs on window. Here, `window.read()` will create the GUI of the window before update if GUI not yet finalized, then update the GUI of the window

```py
    while True:             # Event Loop
        event, values = window.read()
    ...
```

4. Break from while loop if event of close button of window clicked, or event of 'Exit' button clicked.

```py
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break
```

5. Start a new thread by call function `the_thread(window)` if button 'Start A Thread' clicked.

```py
        if event.startswith('Start'):
            threading.Thread(target=the_thread, args=(window,), daemon=True).start()
```

6. Thread function send one event `'-THREAD-'` every sleep one second with value `(threading.current_thread().name, i)`. In general, you should not update GUI of window not in main thread for you may get troubles when your code running, send a event to main thread to handle GUI update, so I removed all `cp` calls here.

```py
def the_thread(window):

    i = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        window.write_event_value('-THREAD-', (threading.current_thread().name, i))      # Data sent is a tuple of thread name and counter
        i += 1
```

7. Update elements or window, and print messages to `sg.Multiline` when event `-THREAD-` generated from thread.

```py
        if event == THREAD_EVENT:
            cp(f'Data from the thread ', colors='white on purple', end='')
            cp(f'{values[THREAD_EVENT]}', colors='white on red')
```

8. After break from while loop, close `window` and exit.

```py
    window.close()
```

Comment: Sorry I was new to python and I am still learning, my question was why the window's attributes was updated in a separate function and how it was accessed from there when it is in main.

I realized now that when you pass a mutable object, you can modify its attributes, be it a list or a class object. It's a stupid question, sorry for the trouble. I'll continue studying to learn more about the language.